# Gdiplus Bitmap error

Tags: gdi+

I'm trying to convert an HBITMAP to a Gdiplus Bitmap. My code is getting a screenshot with some code I found from google and putting it in an HBITMAP. I want to get the rgb values (specifically argb) using Gdiplus.

The code getting the screenshot works file, but the line that turns the HBITMAP into a Bitmap throws a ton of crazy linker errors. Here is my code:

```
HDC hScreenDC = CreateDC((LPCWSTR)"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);     
// and a device context to put it in
HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);

int x = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, HORZRES);
int y = GetDeviceCaps(hScreenDC, VERTRES);

// maybe worth checking these are positive values
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, x, y);

// get a new bitmap
HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hBitmap);

BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, 1920, 1080, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
hBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap);

// clean up
DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
DeleteDC(hScreenDC);

Gdiplus::Bitmap* pBitmap = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromHBITMAP( hBitmap, NULL ); // <-- problem line
```

The liner error is a LNK2019 and says:
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _GdipFree@4 referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl Gdiplus::GdiplusBase::operator delete(void *)" (??3GdiplusBase@Gdiplus@@SAXPAX@Z)

I have included gdiplus.h, windows.h, and #define GDIPVER 0x110

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First thing to check - have you linked to gdiplus.lib? That's very likely the problem.

Also make sure that you've called [GdiplusStartup()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms534077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at some point before you start using the GDI+ functions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link your project to `gdiplus.lib`.

```
#include "Gdiplus.h"
#pragma comment(lib,"gdiplus.lib")
```

Checkout this [post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533895(v=vs.85).aspx) as an example.